# I have set the DKIM record but my emails is not signed?

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have set the DKIM record on my DNS server provider (Cloudflare) and i tested it using different online tools which all says that my dkim record is valid but all my messages i sent dont have DKIm signature on it which cause the messages sometimes to go to spam folder. This is my domain "bon amico'DOT'de" and im using hostgator shared hosting which use CPanel

Thanks and would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

DNS record is not for signing but for validating with public key. Your mail server should sign message with private key.